# How to store data from a database in an array for further use

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a database and i fetch my data like this:

```
if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "SELECT mat.nome AS nome FROM materiali AS mat
 JOIN campo_di_utilizzo_materiali AS cum ON cum.id_materiali=mat.idmateriali
 JOIN campo_di_utilizzo as cu ON cu.idcampo_di_utilizzo=cum.id_campo GROUP BY mat.nome;";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$nome = array();
while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

$nome[]=$db_field['nome'];




   mysql_close($db_handle);


}
print_r ($nome);
```

my print_r show an array like associative array.
I need to do a foreach to fill my option box

```
foreach $nome as $random_variable_name {
 echo ......fill textbox here
}
```

but i Always get a blank page. what i don't get
EDIT CODE IN HTML

```
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Scegli una categoria</option>
     <?php foreach($nome) as ($sceltacategoria) {
   echo '<option value="1"> '.$sceltacategoria.'</option>';}
   ?>
</select>
```

EDIT 2
When i print array with print_r it show me that like this :

Array([0]=>1rstfield [1]=> ) ecc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

incorrect foreach construction:

```
foreach ($nome as $random_variable_name) {
```

PS: Try to turn on error reporting while developing.

Comment: True, but reasonably safe to assume that because the echo line of that foreach is obviously written for example that perhaps the actual foreach syntax would be OK too? OP should definitely have posted proper code though.

Comment: OK - after his edit I can see you happen to be correct

Comment: I will turn on error reporting. that is done from php.ini. Right? thank you and sorry for the stupid question. after whole day I was too tired to notice that.

Comment: @user3384514 You can also set it at runtime (preferably distinguish with an `if` if you are in developing or production mode) ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php